# Two keys with same name but different values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a program which prompts the user for a location, contact a web service and retrieve json. Then it is required to parse the data and retrieve
the first "place_id" key. Now here the cookies crumble. There are two keys with same name "place_id" but different values. As indices doesn't work with dictionary, what is the solution?

```
items=js['results']
for items in js['results']:
    placeid['place_id']=items['place_id']
    print(placeid)
```

I want the output to be

```
{'place_id': 'ChIJVUqIm-fP20YRj5roNMigAqg'}
```

But I am getting

```
{'place_id': 'ChIJVUqIm-fP20YRj5roNMigAqg'}
{'place_id': 'ChIJs4tH49_P20YRMW0pE5A376M'}
```

Comment: If you only want the first, just add a break when you find something

Answer (score 0):

If you can update value by key the just use  this one:

```
dict.update({'key1': 'value1'})
```